# logistic 3 way interaction with MLR estimator in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, robust

I am trying to recreate the analysis of a certain set of data that was originally done in MPlus, instead using R. However, I do not know how to specify an MLR estimator with logistic regression in R.

My original model looks like this:

```
Model1_logit <- glm(formula = Voluntary_Turnover_measure ~ IV_customerinjustice * Mod1_performance * Mod2_exhaustion
                     + dem_age + Demands + DJ + PJ + IntJ + InfJ, 
                family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = SIOP_REDUCED_DATA, na.rm=TRUE)
summary(Model1_logit)
```

Because some of the terms are highly correlated with each other, the researcher who completed this analysis used an MLR estimator for a more robust regression. 
How can I do this in R?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: A sample data set would be helpful to know what are the types of variables such as binary, multiclass, numeric etc. (1) what is the type of response variable Voluntary_Turnover_measure? (2) what does MLR mean here? Thanks.

Comment: Hello! While I cannot provide the data set, the DV (voluntary turnover) is binary, while all other variables in the equation are numeric. The MLR estimator was used in MPlus (Yuan-Bentler correction) instead of the Maximum Likelihood estimator, because some of the variables (DJ, PJ, IntJ, and InfJ) are highly correlated with each other and break the assumption of independence. I'm unsure of how to use the MLR estimator with logistic regression in R.

Answer (score 0):

In the code below the [`lavaan()`](http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/est.html) package is used. Sample data is created based on the question to fit `ML` (`maximum likelihood`). The `likelihood="wishart"`was used similar to MPlus program. The packages can be downloaded from here: [`cfa()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cfa/index.html), [`lavaan()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lavaan/index.html) if manual installation is needed. Please note that the model implementation may vary based on the data and parameters.[Documentation](http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/index.html) discusses alternative ways to set up the model. In this sample model, all factors were not used because it ran into problems with variances.

**Import libraries**

```
library(lavaan)
library(cfa)
```

**Create sample dataframe**

```
# Create sample data
Voluntary_Turnover_measure <- floor(runif(100,0,1.5))
IV_customerinjustice <- abs(rnorm(100,sd=.1))*2
Mod1_performance <- abs(rnorm(100,sd=.1))/10
Mod2_exhaustion <- abs(rnorm(100,sd=.1))/100
dem_age <- abs(floor(runif(100)*100))
Demands <- abs(rnorm(100))
DJ <- abs(rnorm(100))*20
PJ <- abs(rnorm(100))*10
IntJ <- runif(100,1,100)
InfJ <- IntJ**2
plot(IntJ, InfJ)
# Create dataframe
df <- data.frame(Voluntary_Turnover_measure, IV_customerinjustice, Mod1_performance, Mod2_exhaustion,
                 dem_age, Demands, DJ, PJ, IntJ, InfJ)
```

**Normalize dataframe values**

```
df_scaled <- scale(df)
df_scaled[,'Voluntary_Turnover_measure'] <- df[,'Voluntary_Turnover_measure']  # Response variable kept not normalized
```

**Specify the model**

```
model1 <- 'Voluntary_Turnover_measure = ~ DJ + PJ + IntJ + dem_age +  Demands'
```

**Estimate the model parameters**

```
model1.fit <- cfa(model1, data=df_scaled)
summary(model1.fit)
```

**MLR Estimator**

```
mlr.fit <- cfa(model1, 
               data = df_scaled, 
               likelihood = "wishart",
               estimator='MLR'
               )
summary(mlr.fit)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! Just to confirm, I don't need to specify in the lavaan model that it is logistic regression instead of OLS?

Comment: Thanks. I cannot be certain. The docs say that if the `estimator=MML` then the `logit` can be specified in the `link` (default is `probit`). However in the above code `estimator=MLR` was used. I would refer the docs in greater detail to set up the model based on the type of data.